# jhipster aws elastic beanstalk 404

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, jhipster

I trying to deploy a jhipster (spring boot) app to elastic beanstalk using single instance configuration and get http 404 for all static call ( '/' or '/index.html'), I generated the app using jhispter and made the following configuration:

pom.xml:

```
  <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
.....
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>false</executable>
                    </configuration>
```

for the record, api works fine! only static files get 404.

> 2017-07-23 04:34:48.539 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /' doesn't match 'OPTIONS /**
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.539 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/app/**/*.{js,html}'
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.539 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/bower_components/**'
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.539 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/i18n/**'
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.539 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/content/**'
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.539 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/swagger-ui/index.html'
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.539 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/test/**'
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.539 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.539 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.539 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.539 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.539 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.542 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@2e2f941e
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.542 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.543 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.543 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /' doesn't match 'POST /logout
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.543 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.543 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.543 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.543 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.544 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.544 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.544 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.544 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /; Attributes: [permitAll]
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.544 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.544 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@6e7461cd, returned: 1
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.546 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.546 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.546 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.547 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/]
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.549 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.556 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/]
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.557 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/] are [/**]
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.557 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/] are {}
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.557 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/], class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@78226c36]]] and 1 interceptor
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.558 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/] is: -1
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.558 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.558 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.558 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.559 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.559 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.560 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error]
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.565 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /error
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.565 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)]
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.565 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/error] is: -1
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.579 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Requested media types are [text/html, text/html;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and producible media types [text/html])
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.579 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Returning [org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView@ec234ad] based on requested media type 'text/html'
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.579 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView@ec234ad] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
>   2017-07-23 04:34:48.597 DEBUG 30610 --- [nio-5000-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request

from default config jhipster (undertow + executable:true):

```
2017-07-23 10:57:26 UTC-0300    ERROR   [Instance: i-06c0e61a84efdeaf5] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED).../util/SystemPropertyUtils.class Failed to execute '/usr/bin/unzip -o -d /var/app/staging /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle' Failed to execute '/usr/bin/unzip -o -d /var/app/staging /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle'. Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/01_configure_application.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
2017-07-23 10:57:22 UTC-0300    ERROR   Failed to execute '/usr/bin/unzip -o -d /var/app/staging /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle'
```

Comment: Does the app run locally and how is it started? Which version of JHipster? We migrated from Tomcat to Undertow in 3.7.0. I suppose that it's working in aws if you keep default configuration: undertow and executable jar to true?

Comment: Local started ok and work as expected, I using jhipster 4.6.2, locally runs fine in prod or dev profile. I'm using elastic beanstalk with simple java config, not docker.

Comment: Please edit your question to show log as it is unreadable in comments.

Comment: sorry, edit done!

Comment: @longo have you solved the issue? I have same 404 error when deploy jhipster backend to beanstalk by sub-generator

Comment: @HaifengZhang I resolved this issue creating a new app with a new version of jhipster and copying the files that I changed, but couldn't figure out the error.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try it out!